# After upgrade to 1.9 and editor 1.5 to 1.91 build file is missing

Tags: build, dart, editor, upgrade

Pub Build generated files in  ../build were (until yesterday when I upgraded):

```
fireimager_server.dart
fireimager_server.dart.js.map
fireimager_server.dart.js
packages
```

After upgrade to Dart 1.9 and Editor to 1.91

```
fireimager_server.dart
```

is missing and I couldn't start My_Server.dart from a script.

The only problems reported on the build were a couple of variables declared but not used.

What's going on?

My only fix now is to restore to an earlier date from a backup and loose my edits.

EDIT

```
yaml file contents November 2014
```

```yml
name: Server
version: 0.7.1
author: Robert Lockwood
description: A sample web application
dependencies:
  browser: any
  http_server: any
  intl: any
  io: any
  json: any
  json_object: any
  logging: any
  logging_handlers: any
  route: any
  typed_data: any
```

fireimager.html file:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>FireImager</title>
<meta name="description" content="FireImager control GUI">
<meta name="author" content="Robert N Lockwood">
<link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" media="screen" href='fireimager.css'>
<!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"> -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id='main-box'>
    <section>
      <div id='top-box'>
        <div id='img-box'>
          <div id='image-div'>
           <div id='imgAnchor'>
             <img alt='' id='image' src='resources/fi_12_demo.png'
                height='480' width='640'>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id='right-container-box'>
          <div id='log-box'>
            <textarea id='log-area' readonly placeholder='Activity Log'
              cols="1" rows="1"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div id='button-box'>
            <div class='btn-row-container'>
              <button class='command-btn' type='button'
                id='modeToggle-btn'>Mapping</button>
              <button class='command-btn' type='button'
                id='calibrate-btn'>Calibrate</button>
            </div>
            <div class='btn-row-container'>
              <button class='command-btn' type='button'
                id='close-door-btn'>Open Door</button>
              <button class='command-btn' type='button'
                id='tools-btn'>Tools</button>
            </div>
            <div class='btn-row-container'>
              <button class='command-btn' type='button'
                id='mosaic-btn'>New Mosaic</button>
              <button class='command-btn' type='button'
                id='terrain-btn'>Terrain View</button>
            </div>
            <div class='btn-row-container'>
              <button class='command-btn' type='button'
                id='reset-btn'>Update</button>
              <button class='command-btn' type='button'
                id='shutdown-btn'>Shutdown</button>
            </div>
          </div>
         <!-- <div id='app-name-box'>PSW&nbsp;FireImager</div> -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div id='bottom-box'>
        <div class='toolbar' id='toolbar-top'>
          <div id='camera-status'>Camera&nbsp;Not&nbsp;Ready</div>
          <div id='busy-led'>&nbsp;</div>
          <div id='radio-btns' class='radio-btns'>
            <input id='B12' type='radio' name='radio-btn' checked>
              <label id='lblB12' class='radiobutton-label' for='B12'>Fire&nbsp;</label>
            <input id='BWB' type='radio' name='radio-btn' >
              <label id='lblBBW' class='radiobutton-label' for='BWB'>Wide</label>
            <input id='B10' type='radio' name='radio-btn' >
              <label id='lblB10' class='radiobutton-label' for='B10'>B10</label>
            <input id='B08' type='radio' name='radio-btn' >
              <label id='lblB8' class='radiobutton-label' for='B08'>B8&nbsp;</label>
          </div>
          <div id='record-pause'>Record&nbsp;Paused</div>
        </div>
        <div class='toolbar' id='toolbar-bottom'>
          <div id='time-lbl'>Local</div>
          <div id='time-date-text' class='output-box-text'>&nbsp;</div>
          <div id='mission-div'>
            <label for='mission'>Mission</label> <input id='mission'
              placeholder='Mission name' type='text'>
          </div>
          <div id='image-period-div'>
            <label for='img-period'>Period</label>
            <input id='img-period' placeholder='3.500' type='text'>
            <label for='img-period' id='period-lbl'> sec</label>
          </div>
          <div id='mosaic-lbl' class='output-box-text'>Mosaic</div>
          <div id='mosaic-number-div' class='output-box-text'>1</div>
          <div id='imageID-lbl'>ImageID</div>
          <div id='ImageID-div' class='output-box-text'>0</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id='icon-box'><img alt='' id='icon' src='resources/FS-Shield-Transparent.png'
              height='80' width='72'></div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <script type='application/dart' src='fireimager.dart'></script>
  <script src='packages/browser/dart.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have an *.html file as well? How does your `pubspec.yaml` file look like? How does your `index.html` file look like? Can you please add these files to your question.

Comment: I've added the files you requested, Günter. I should add that this is the only Dart code I've ever written (web page and micro-server) and the only web page I've ever written as well. If I restore the Dart work space to the 26th from backup everything works. p.s. I notice that in the updated editor the build command no longer says 'builds js' and there are about 1000 fewer files created after the build.  Am I building incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are now two `Pub Build` menues in DartEditor maybe you used the first one `Pub Build - minified` which doesn't copy the Dart files. If you run `Pub Build - Debug` the Dart file might be copied (not sure because I never used it this way for server side scripts).

If you move the `fireimager_server.dart` file in the `bin` directory of you package then you can just run it with `dart bin/fireimager_server.dart` or you can just copy it manually to the build directory.
The `bin` directory is the right directory for server side scripts according to the package layout guidelines.

If it was copied to `build` previously it indicates that you had it in the `web` directory which isn't the right place for server side Dart.

**Update**

You usually use `Pub Build - minified` for production. `Pub Build`'s output is what should be served to the browser and shouldn't contain `fireimager_server.dart`. `fireimager_server.dart` script is a server application and needs to be deployed differently. Therefore it should go into the `bin` directory. There are currently no perfect options for server side deployment but just copying your package to the server and run `pub get` should do it so you can run the server using `dart bin/fireimager_server.dart`. If `fireimager_server.dart` acts as a web server and serves the build output this deployment variant works as well. Just use `build` as static-directory.

Comment: I was building by right clicking on yaml and using that menu.  Using the menu under tools works but I'm a little confused by building the production app by choosing build -debug!

Comment: I extended my answer.